# Php show info after a set date

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi and thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I currently have a Php script that allows me to hide content after a set date and replace it with a default text, you can see it below:

```html
      <?php if (date('Y-m-d') <= '2018-05-30') { ?> 
          <li><p><strong>Apply to Graduate:</strong></p>
          <p><a href="app-graduate-form.php" class="applyBtn">Apply to Graduate</a></p>
          </li>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <p><li><strong>The application to graduate is not available at this time.</strong> If you qualify to graduate, the Registrar’s Office will notify you when the application to graduate is available.</li></p>
        <?php } ?>
```

What I am trying to do now is add an extra script that turns it back on in a set date so basically it functions both ways, hiding content after a set date and then activate the content once another date comes, I have been having a hard time figuring it out and I would love if you can give me a hand!

Thanks a lot for your time and your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding elseif but no luck so far.

Comment: @Aztlan, I see `Aztlan` & `Lawrence Cherone` are same persons. Isn't that  ^^^ (: ^^^ ? Well done boy.

Answer (score 0):

The logic would be to add the latest date first and the earliest last. Something like:

if date >= 2018-08-30

*what happens after the second date*

elseif date <= 2018-05-30

*What happens before the first date*

else

*What happens in between*

This works because once a condition is fulfilled it breaks off the else/if statement.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try. So if I am understanding right after else I will put my message that I currently have which is "The application to graduate is not available at this time." and then on if and elseif I will have:                                <li><p><strong>Apply to Graduate:</strong></p>
          <p><a href="app-graduate-form.php" class="applyBtn">Apply to Graduate</a></p>
          </li>                                                                                                                       Which will enable the button again, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do it like this if you are hardcoding dates, mainly so I don't have to come back to the script too much ;p

Have an array of dates, then match the closest start date then check that today is between the start and end of the matched array.

```
<?php
$dates = [
    ['start' => '2018-05-30', 'end' => '2018-06-30'],
    ['start' => '2018-07-26', 'end' => '2018-08-30'], // matches this
    ['start' => '2018-09-30', 'end' => '2018-10-30'],
];

function closest_key($dates, $date) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($dates as $value) {
        $result[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($value));
    }
    asort($result);
    return key($result);
}

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date = $dates[closest_key(array_column($dates, 'start'), $today)];

if ($today >= $date['start'] && $today <= $date['end']) {
    echo 'Apply to Graduate';
} else {
    echo 'The application to graduate is not available at this time.';
}
```

**Result *(today is 2018-07-27)*:**

```
Apply to Graduate
```

https://3v4l.org/LGpv8

If the date was `2018-09-01` it would be false.

The same idea could also be done in Javascript, with a little porting.

Comment: Lawrence thanks a lot for your time and response, I see that it makes sense that way I would just set up the dates and let it do its thing, I tried using your code but it makes the site stop functioning I see that its missing a php closing bracket at the end but even after adding that it doesnt work.

Comment: no probs, yeah you're prob missing a quote or something when putting your html back.

Answer (score -1):

Updated answer.

Say, based on the scenario in your question and comment the offer expires first time after 5 days from today `$currentdate` which is your `$first_expire_date`. if you want to start the offer 2nd time again after 10 days from today & keep continue it for further 15 days from 2nd time offer start date, you shall try to use,

```
<?php
    // Today
    $currentdate = date('Y-m-d'); 

    // Offer starts. Set it as you want. You can set it to '2018-05-30' in that case you already get $first_expire_date expires.
    $offer_start_date = '2018-07-28';    

    // You can add +220 days, or +1 month or +2 years in the following snippet as you prefer
    // You can also subtract -3 months or -11 years or -1 day as you need
    $first_expire_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+5 days',strtotime($offer_start_date )));

    //2nd time offer start date
    $second_valid_date_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+5 days',strtotime($first_expire_date)));

    //2nd time offer end date
    $second_valid_date_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+15 days',strtotime($second_valid_date_start)));
    ?>


    <?php if ($currentdate  <= $first_expire_date) { ?> 
    <li><p><strong>Apply to Graduate:</strong></p>
    <p><a href="app-graduate-form.php" class="applyBtn">Apply to Graduate</a></p>
    </li>
    <?php }else  ?>

    <?php if (isset($second_valid_date_start) && ($second_valid_date_start <= $second_valid_date_end)) { ?> 
    <li><p><strong>Apply to Graduate:</strong></p>
    <p><a href="app-graduate-form.php" class="applyBtn">Apply to Graduate</a></p>
    </li>
    <?php }else{ ?>

    <p><li><strong>The application to graduate is not available at this time.</strong> If you qualify to graduate, the Registrar’s Office will notify you when the application to graduate is available.</li></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to change the date of today to the end date which in this case I used 2018-05-30 as the example. So re-validate after 120 days from the date it was taken down.

Comment: of course. I just give an example based on your code so that you can understand it. I'm also changing the example so that you can implement it on the fly without any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your response, would you be kind enough to edit your code to re-validate after the 2018-05-30 date that I used as an example? I am a noob on Php, that way it would make more sense for me. I appreciate your time and responses.

Comment: @AztlanI, I updated the answer. If you still don't understand it or have any question, please let me know.